# Problem to install scikit-learn in custom virtual enviroment folder

Tags: scikit-learn, python-venv

I am trying to manage in my .venv folder, which I have created with the following command in the root of my project

```
python -m venv venv
```

I activate it with the following command:

```
source .venv/bin/activate
```

And when installing 'scikit-learn'

```
pip install scikit-learn
```

I use python 3.10

It gave me an error like:

```
(.venv) PS C:\XX\XX\XX\XX\python\flask-data-analysis> pip install scikit-learn   
Collecting scikit-learn
  Using cached scikit-learn-1.3.2.tar.gz (7.5 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [57 lines of output]
      Ignoring oldest-supported-numpy: markers 'python_version != "3.10" or platform_system != "Windows" or platform_python_implementation == "PyPy"' don't match your environment
      Collecting setuptools
        Using cached setuptools-68.2.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.3 kB)
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.41.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
      Collecting Cython<3.0,>=0.29.33
        Using cached Cython-0.29.36-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.1 kB)
      Collecting numpy==1.22.3
        Using cached numpy-1.22.3-cp310-cp310-win32.whl (12.2 MB)
      Collecting scipy>=1.5.0
        Using cached scipy-1.11.3.tar.gz (56.3 MB)
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
        Installing backend dependencies: started
        Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error
     
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1
     
        [21 lines of output]
        + meson setup C:\XX\XX\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wn83bmfl\scipy_c2cf1e0fecc34ad19a2d56fcaf313dc8 C:\Users\nm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wn83bmfl\scipy_c2cf1e0fecc34ad19a2d56fcaf313dc8\.mesonpy-bj7ca394 -Dbuil
dtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --native-file=C:\XX\XX\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wn83bmfl\scipy_c2cf1e0fecc34ad19a2d56fcaf313dc8\.mesonpy-bj7ca394\meson-python-native-file.ini
        The Meson build system
        Version: 1.2.3
        Source dir: C:\XX\XX\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wn83bmfl\scipy_c2cf1e0fecc34ad19a2d56fcaf313dc8
        Build dir: C:\XX\XX\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wn83bmfl\scipy_c2cf1e0fecc34ad19a2d56fcaf313dc8\.mesonpy-bj7ca394
        Build type: native build
        Project name: SciPy
        Project version: 1.11.3
        WARNING: Failed to activate VS environment: Could not find C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe
     
        ..\meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['icl'], ['cl'], ['cc'], ['gcc'], ['clang'], ['clang-cl'], ['pgcc']]
        The following exception(s) were encountered:
        Running `icl ""` gave "[WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado"
        Running `cl /?` gave "[WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado"
        Running `cc --version` gave "[WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado"
        Running `gcc --version` gave "[WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado"
        Running `clang --version` gave "[WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado"
        Running `clang-cl /?` gave "[WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado"
        Running `pgcc --version` gave "[WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado"
     
        A full log can be found at C:\XX\XX\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wn83bmfl\scipy_c2cf1e0fecc34ad19a2d56fcaf313dc8\.mesonpy-bj7ca394\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
        [end of output]
     
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: metadata-generation-failed
     
      Encountered error while generating package metadata.
     
      See above for output.
     
      note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
      hint: See above for details.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I attach an image (Packages in my project and requirements.txt) with the python interpreter of my project

[Packages in my project and requirements.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfgfJ.png)

I have seen that it requires the following libraries to install sklearn:
numpy, scipy, joblib, threadpoolctl and cython.
These packages are installed as you can see in my interpreter (in the screenshot) but I keep getting the same error and I don't know if I am missing something at the environment level, required packages...

I tried installing the required packages, resetting the environment, installing it globally, also updating pip & setuptools

Comment: I solved this with the params ' -U --only-binary :all:' :
"
pip install numpy -U --only-binary :all:
pip install tensorflow -U --only-binary :all:
pip install pandas -U --only-binary :all:
pip install scikit-learn -U --only-binary :all:
"